# Spring boot always returns a 404 error

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to get a Spring Boot (1.5.9) project to respond with a simple Hello world message. However, any request I send it immediately returns a 404 exception.

**MyBackendApplication**

```
package net.mypackage.backend;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyBackendApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyBackendApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**controllers/HelloController**

```
package net.mypackage.backend.controllers;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello, world!";
    }

}
```

**application.properties**

```
server.port = 5000
server.contextPath=/
logging.level.org=DEBUG
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.9.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

group = 'net.mypackage'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey')
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
}
```

When requesting a page (`localhost:5000/hello`), I get a 404 error. The following information shows in the log for this request ([here](https://gist.github.com/cascer1/d068d31c31fb9b4c52aa813364318e24) is a gist, because I don't like the way this is formatted as a quote):

> 2018-02-05 13:01:37.600 DEBUG 17448 --- [nio-5000-exec-2]
>   o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Received [GET / HTTP/1.1
>   cache-control: no-cache   User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.1.1   Accept:
>   */*   Host: 127.0.0.1:5000   accept-encoding: gzip, deflate   Connection: keep-alive      ]   2018-02-05 13:01:37.601 DEBUG 17448
>   --- [nio-5000-exec-2]  o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Security checking request GET /   2018-02-05 13:01:37.601 DEBUG 17448
>   --- [nio-5000-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase      :   No applicable constraints defined   2018-02-05 13:01:37.601 DEBUG 17448
>   --- [nio-5000-exec-2] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    :  Not subject to any constraint   2018-02-05 13:01:37.604 DEBUG 17448 ---
>   [nio-5000-exec-2] o.a.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase    : Socket: 
>   [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@4bfc0a6:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@b945368:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected
>   local=/127.0.0.1:5000 remote=/127.0.0.1:53684]], Read from buffer: [0]
>   2018-02-05 13:01:37.604 DEBUG 17448 --- [nio-5000-exec-2]
>   o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Socket:
>   [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@4bfc0a6:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@b945368:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected
>   local=/127.0.0.1:5000 remote=/127.0.0.1:53684]], Status in:
>   [OPEN_READ], State out: [OPEN]

I'm sure I missed something very basic, but I can't for the life of me figure out what. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: First of all if you don't want to keep context path then remove `server.contextPath` from there. By default it'll be on `ip:port`

Comment: @user3145373ツThanks, I saw a recommendation elsewhere to add a context path of `/`. I removed it from my application config but still have the same problem.

Comment: Can you please list down the pom.xml config and dependencies.

Comment: From the logs it looks like it is looking for / instead of /hello - `Security checking request GET / `

Comment: @CasEliëns: I just tried same code from your.  spring-boot-starter-web in pom.xml It's working fine in my machine.

Comment: @user3145373ツi added my `build.gradle` file to the question. I don't have a `pom.xml`

Comment: Fix your gradle dependencies. It should have `compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")`, Actually try just with: `dependencies {compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")}`

Comment: @CrazySabbath Thanks! Adding that dependency fixed my issue. Weird how it wasn't included by the project setup in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

Info you provided is not enough.

When I tried your Application and Controller with this pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>mvc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>MVC</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

it works with both `server.contextPath=/` and also when commented out.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me, there's no single character beyond the below code to run spring boot simple API. I think there's some config class or pom issue in your application.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**HelloController.java**

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello, world!";
    }
}
```

**DemoApplication.java**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
server.port = 5000
logging.level.org=DEBUG
```

**Running successfully**

[image]